# Putting file in same directory as Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, directory

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.read_csv('the_traits.txt')
```

I am trying to upload a txt document with data into python. It says there is an error and I'm guessing its because it isnt in the same directory? How would I make sure the file is in the same directory?

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'the_traits.txt' does not exist: b'the_traits.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

open jupyter notebooks and you will see upload button, upload the file from your whichever folder is it there and try it. It will work

or

you also can give absolute path in file that will also do the job for you

Comment: Mark this as answer if it ansers your question